# Issues with SQL import and colons

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-import-wizard

I am trying to import a tab-separated file with no text qualifiers that contains about 8 million records with 700 columns.  The issue I am having is that there is a field that is causing the import to fail.
the output is:
Executing (Error)
Messages

> Error 0xc02020a1: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "Assessment_District" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".
> (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

> Error 0xc020902a: Data Flow Task 1: The "Source - view10_txt.Outputs[Flat File Source Output].Columns[ColumnName]" failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition on "Source - view10_txt.Outputs[Flat File Source Output].Columns[ColumnName]" specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.
> (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

> Error 0xc0202092: Data Flow Task 1: An error occurred while processing file "C:...\view10.txt" on data row 59.
> (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

> Error 0xc0047038: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Source - view10_txt returned error code 0xC0202092.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
> (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Typical annoyance in getting an import to work, but the reason is really odd. Through a process of elimination, I have figured out that occasionally this column has two colons in it *i.e. ADAMS CNTY MTA 5 (CONCORD: MCKEE: BEVERLY & RICHFIELD)* that I am trying to import into a varchar(100) field. if I remove one of the colons everything works.

Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this that does not involve manipulating the import file?

Comment: If the file is tab delimited, the colon (`:`) character won't be affecting this, the fact is that the column you have defined in your data flow is too small for the value. That is what the error is telling you, and that will be the issue. That doesn't mean the value in the SQL table, but in the actual dataset(s) defined in your Data Source and Data Flow.

Comment: Side note, a table with 700 columns seems like a huge denormalisation issue.

Comment: Deleting a single colon to make it work sounds bogus. I'd be checking the table for triggers that audit this column using a char(54) data type or are doing logic on this column based on colon characters.

Comment: Got it resolved. The colon just happened to be in the 51st position and the definition of the source data was limited to 50 characters.